# Why are touchDragExit and touchDragEnter being called repetitively multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[`UIControlEventTouchDragExit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents/uicontroleventtouchdragexit) is

> "an event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside
>   its bounds"

[`UIControlEventTouchDragEnter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents/uicontroleventtouchdragenter) is

> "an event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control"

If I simulate a constant drag down, essentially exiting the bounds of the control once, **why are `touchDragExit` and `touchDragEnter` being called multiple times?**

[image: touch drag enter exit gif]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let btn = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100), image:UIImage())
        btn.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    init(frame: CGRect, image:UIImage?) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addTargets()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func addTargets() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDown), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpInside), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDragExit), for: UIControlEvents.touchDragExit)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDragEnter), for: UIControlEvents.touchDragEnter)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchCancel), for: UIControlEvents.touchCancel)
    }

    func touchDown() {
        print("touched down")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        },completion: nil)
    }

    func touchUpInside() {
        print("touch up inside")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 9.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func touchDragExit() {
        print("touch drag exit")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        }, completion: nil)

    }

    func touchDragEnter() {
        print("touch drag enter")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        },completion: nil)
    }

    func touchCancel() {
        print("touch canceled")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the size of the end of your finger compared to the size of a pixel (particularly on a Retina display).  There's a lot of room for error in that relative difference.  The OS has to make some estimations to figure out exactly where your finger is "pointing" on the screen and as you wiggle your finger that estimation might change slightly.  As a result figuring out whether your finger is inside or outside of a one pixel boundary can be a bit tough and some fluctuation is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

it is bcz of changing view frame by scale `self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)`

for example try change background color instead of scale and it will be ok