# UIButton touchDragEnter and touchDragExit called too often

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, core-animation, uiviewanimation

How can I avoid a UIButtons .touchDragEnter and .touchDragExit functions from rapid firing? [This question demonstrates the issue perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750801/why-are-touchdragexit-and-touchdragenter-being-called-repetitively-multiple-time), but the only answer does not describe how to work around it. I'm trying to animate a button when the users finger on the button, and animate it again when their finger slides off. Are there any better ways to do this? If not, how should I stop my animation code from firing multiple times when the users finger is right between an .enter and an .exit state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead track the location of the touch point itself and determine when the touch point moves in and out of the button

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        // moving in to the button
        if button.frame.contains(point) && !wasInButton {
            // trigger animation
            wasInButton = true
        }
        // moving out of the button
        if !button.frame.contains(point) && wasInButton {
            // trigger animation
            wasInButton = false
        }
    }
}
```

*wasInButton* could be a boolean variable set to true when there is a touch down in the button's frame:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        if button.frame.contains(point) {
            wasInButton = true
            // trigger animation
        } else {
            wasInButton = false
        }
    }
```

This would require you to subclass the button's superview. And since you might not want to animate as soon as the point leaves the button's frame (because the user's finger or thumb would still be covering most of the button), you could instead do the hit test in a larger frame that encapsulates your button.